# List databases in TFS Application trier only configuration error

Tags: team-foundation-server

I have an application trier (APPTR1) an an data trier (SQLSRVR) installed
Now I am trying to install a second application trier(APPTR2) to use in a cluster with apptr1

i have installed tfs on apptr2, and i am going to the application trier only configuration wizard.
i am logged in with the domain account _sTFSService (which i also used on apptr1)
I fill in SQLSRVR and i click on the button list available databases.

Now i get an error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

all are server 2012 boxes , and i'm using tis 2013.
Sqlserver is 2014 version

Any idea why i get this error or where i can find some more detailed error information?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

My SQL Server instance contained two other databases with the same name but with status (failed) . Removing those databases fixed the problem.